# 3D animation in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: 3d, arcgis-pro, animation

I have been hearing about ArcGIS Pro and its 3D abilities from here and there in the last few days. I haven't used it till now, but I am wondering if it is able to produce 3D animation of flow of surface water in a city, just for presentation purposes.

I have got a series of rasters depicting water depth values at different time instants from simulations and it would be really effective if I could show it in the form of an animation of flow of water over that time series with a background of a 3D city.

I would be glad to hear if anyone has tried similar things in ArcGIS Pro or if anyone has a better idea of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I would try out the Range Slider as explained here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/working-with-a-multidimensional-raster-layer.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_906746FD19C741888234B5BCDED45CFD. After you set the time properties, you can follow the steps here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/animation/animate-through-time.htm.